# Linux snap application

Tags: linux, snapshot, fanotify

I want to monitor by FANOTIFY the Linux applications installed  by snap but I was not able to do this, just applications installed by "apt-get" or "yum". The documentation is very weak and this task is a must to make my application suitable for all situations. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Why would you use `fanotify`? Why not like watch the logs `journalctl -u snapd`?

Comment: The application is written in C++ and there is no other tool for monitoring files.